# Broken Harvester: harvesting EVERYTHING

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Playing on FTB:Monster and for some reason my last two solo games the Harvester is harvesting EVERYTHING, turning jungle and forest in to rolling hills, for MILES. The planters plant in their proper zone, the harvester thinks the planet IS its zone.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/30k4a5/my_mfr_harvester_got_caught_in_the_forest/).  This is a side effect of the harvester's attempt to harvest entire trees. It attempts to search a large distance away for leaves connected to the current tree it is harvesting so it can handle larger trees that expand outside of the harvesting range.  If you are running your tree farm in the middle of a dense forest, then it will see all the adjacent trees as part of one big "tree".  So you need to put your tree farm in a non-forested area or up in the sky.

You can configure the distance that the harvester will "look" for connected leaves/wood blocks to harvest a tree in `/config/powercrystals/minefactoryreloaded/common.cfg` - I think these are the default values below:

> ```
> searchdistance {
>     I:FruitTree.MaxHoriztonal=5
>     I:FruitTree.MaxVertical=20
>     I:PassengerRail.MaxHorizontal=3
>     I:PassengerRail.MaxVertical=2
>     I:StackingBlock.MaxVertical=5
>     I:Tree.MaxHorizontal=512   **** CHANGE THIS
>     I:Tree.MaxVertical=256     **** CHANGE THIS
> }
> ```